# How can I make keep-alive working in vue?

Tags: vue.js, keep-alive, element-ui

There are form, table and pagination in the page list. I want to keep the form input, table data and current page number unchanged after back from `detail.vue`, but it always refreshes every time.

Do I need to store the form data, table data and page number in somewhere so as to make it works? Thanks.

router

```
{      
    path: '/list',  
    name: 'List',      
    component: resolve => require(['@/pages/list'], resolve),    
    meta: {          
        keepAlive: true 
    }    
}
```

App.vue

```
<div class="app">
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view v-if="$route.meta.keepAlive"></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view v-if="!$route.meta.keepAlive"></router-view>
</div>
```

list.vue

pagination is inside component ListTable

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="100px">
      <el-form-item label="MID" prop="name">
        <el-input v-model="form.mid" />
      </el-form-item>    
      <el-form-item label="Name" prop="name">
        <el-input v-model="form.name" />
      </el-form-item>    
      <el-form-item label="Birthdate" prop="birthdate">
        <el-date-picker
          v-model="form.birthdate"
          value-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
        />
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
    <ListTable ref="childTable" :listdata="listData" :currpage="currPage" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MemberList',
  components: {
    ListTable: () => import('@/components/Membership/ListTable')
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currPage: 1,
      listData: [],
      form: {
        mid: '',
        name: '',
        birthdate: '',
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      // get list data
      this.listData = ***
      .....
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need set key for your component to `keep-alive` makes difference between rendered components

```
<keep-alive>
      <router-view v-if="$route.meta.keepAlive" :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

Second you should put ListTable to another `keep-alive` to inform vue you want store rendered component too

```
<keep-alive>
      <ListTable ref="childTable" :listdata="listData" :currpage="currPage" :key="currPage"/>
</keep-alive>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work too. I found `mounted()` is called when back. The form is not a imported component, its text input also return to blank when back.